# Sony SDK to Transfer Images

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Does the Sony SDK support image transfer?

I have read their documentation and seen only methods to transfer lists and counts of images.  Also, if they do support image transfer, do they support image transfer/control over a direct hardware link rather than WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, latest SDK supports content transfer of images and videos.
Also remote playback is available on latest Action Cam HDR-AZ1 and also on QX1, DSC-QX30 cameras
Camera Remote API is only available over Wi-Fi.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team

Comment: I don't think this is true, the [Camera Remote API](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/) says "Transfer Images: No" practically for all cameras. I want to upload all images to my SFTP server each time I charge the camera in the hotel or elsewhere thru their WiFi. Sony is trying to monetize the API, which is weird given that mobile phones are already way more capable in API wise.